# Angular override global ErrorHandler

Tags: angular

We use a global error handler in our project. The problem is that we got a special case now that we would like to handle separately but we cannot. The global error handler is basically provided in the `app.module.ts`:

```
{ provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: GlobalErrorHandler },
```

We divide between the errors and then handle them with a service.

```
  handleError(error: any): void {
    const errorService = this.injector.get(ErrorService);
    const notifier = this.injector.get(NotificationService);

    let message: string;

    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      message = errorService.getServerErrorMessage(error);
      notifier.showError(message);
    } else if (error === undefined) {
      message = errorService.getServerErrorMessage(error);
      notifier.showError(message);
    } else if (error instanceof Observable) {
      message = this.translate.instant('ERROR.SERVER_NOT_REACHABLE');
      notifier.showError(message);
    } else {
      message = errorService.getClientErrorMessage(error);
      notifier.showError(message);
    }

    this.logger.error(message, `\n - Stacktrace: \n${error.stack}`);
  }
```

The problem now is that we know for some application that if status code 406 is returned for that special call it means that AWS couldn't recognize a face. We would like to return this translated message and try to add an if-clause after the `subscribe()` of the function that calls the backend API.

```
  (err) => {
    if (err.statusCode == 406) {
      this.notifier.showError(
        this.translate.instant(
          'APPLICATIONS.FACE_DETECTION.NOTIFICATION.FACE_ERROR'
        )
      );
    }
  }
```

Instead of achieving anything like this we just get the error message of the backend (that's the right behaviour because we tell to do this in the `ErrorHandlerService` but how to override or to tell that it should not care for that special call?

Comment: You could maybe provide an http interceptor to return some other error for statuscode 406 while you're handling the error in the interceptor; would that work?

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for AWS response and in your first clause of your error handler check if that your http code is 406 and the http response has x props to make sure it's AWS response.

```
if (typeof e.error === 'object' && (e.error as 
AWSError)?.errorCode) {
      const awsError = e.error as AWSError;
}
...
console.log(awsError.errorMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching it in the pipe of the http request using catchError?

```
.pipe(
  catchError(err => {
     if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse && err.status == 406) {
       // handle error
     }
  }).subscribe(res => ...)
```